# how to allow regex search '\xcf\x83' this kind string

Tags: python-3.x

```
pattern = compile(r"(?<=\>)\d{1,4}\.(?=\s)")
input_string = "some string with \xcf\x83 code"

print(pattern.search(input_string))
```

but pattern seach ignore with utf-8 encode value like `\xcf`
how to allow that

Answer (score 0):

use r-string format for the input string and the pattern `r""` this way the special characters will not be translated but stay the same. in the pattern use an extra \ infront of the \ characters to signal regex that the following \ has to be searched and is not the start of a special character

```
import re
print(re.compile(r"\\xcf\\x83").search(r"some string with \xcf\x83 code"))
# <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(17, 25), match='\\xcf\\x83'>
```